# android reload content of first page after onbackpressed from a second page

Tags: android, webview, reload

My app decrypts a webpage stored in the android assets folder and displays it in an activity containing a webview. The decrypted html document contains links to internal anchors at the top of the page and links to other webdocuments. When the back button is pressed after jumping to an internal anchor, the webpage returns to the top of the page as expected. However, if the back button is pressed from a second web page, the webview is blank. A second back press returns the user to the main activity as expected. Is there a way to reload the original web content appropriately and detect when this should be done? Thanks!

```
public class ReviewDocsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView browser;
    String SEED = "password";
    String htmlText = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String inputData = null;
        String htmlText = "";

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String name = bundle.getString("FileName");
        if(name != null)
        {
            browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

            try {
                inputData = myReadAssetsFile(name); //read the encrypted data
            } catch (Exception e) {
                finish();
            }
            try {
                if(inputData != null)
                htmlText = SimpleCrypto.decrypt(SEED, inputData); //decrypt it to "htmlText"
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.v("encode error", ""+e);
            }

            browser.loadDataWithBaseURL("app:html", htmlText, "text/html", "utf-8", null); //load htlText into the browser
            browser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            }
        else
            finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (browser.canGoBack()) {
            browser.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try calling respective data loading on `onResume()`?

Comment: I have not, since my assumption is that the activity itself has not being returned to or altered by jumping to another webpage, just the webview that is within the activity is changing. However, I will give it a try.

Comment: @Shaishav - Thank you for the suggestion. However, I added an "onresume" block. It is called when the activity starts, but it does not get called when the back button is pressed while interacting with the webview's content.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on your `onBackPressed()` and check the state of browser? Maybe call `WebBackForwardList wbfl = browser.copyBackForwardList();`...to check its status...

Comment: The webview is returning to the right page, but since I decrypted the file during oncreate, the actual clear html file does not seem to exist. Although not very elegant, I decided to store the clear html in a temporary file and delete it in onDestroy. This does work, but I hope someone can offer a more elegant solution.

Comment: Can you decrypt again right before calling `browser.goBack()`?. Might be bit slow, but..still safer